# Launch a new page on Clicking a push notification?

Tags: azure, windows-8, push-notification

I am trying to launch an explicit page whenever user clicks on an push notification  to demonstrate a concept.

This code used to work earlier(last year) but i dont remember what i changed in the interim that it stopped working.

Here is the code for app.xaml .

```
private async void AcquirePushChannel()
     {
         try
         {
             CurrentChannel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
             new MessageDialog("Cannot Contact Azure Server", "Operation Timed Out");

         }
         IMobileServiceTable<Registrations> registrationsTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<Registrations>();
         var registration = new Registrations { Handle = CurrentChannel.Uri };
         await registrationsTable.InsertAsync(registration);



     }




    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
    /// will be used when the application is launched to open a specific file, to display
    /// search results, and so forth.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
    protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;


        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args.Arguments))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }
        string launchstring = args.Arguments;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(launchstring))
        {
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(InstructionSetBlue));
        }
            AcquirePushChannel();


        // Ensure the current window is active
     Window.Current.Activate();

    }
```

This piece of code launches the specific page.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(launchstring))
            {
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(InstructionSetBlue));
            }
```

Comment: Are you getting anything in the launchstring?

Comment: The Azure Mobile Service push notification mechanism has changed.  It now uses Azure Notification Hubs.  Have you checked the most recent documentation?  http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-push/

Comment: @FilipSkakun I have put a breakpoint on launch string. It never gets called when Push notification is clicked. Anything i need to do here?

Comment: @sebastus ,it should still work with VS 2012. The problem here is nothing happens when push notification is clicked on.

Comment: @FilipSkakun I have figured it out ,but i am still doing some small mistake. So you to specify launch string in Azure JS itself. This is my script --http://pastebin.com/zvh75Pm3